# Intellij2016 Angular2 sass warnigns for :host selector

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, angular

Angular 2 has this special selector to reference its own component like:

```
:host
  display: block
  height: 100% !important
  width: 100%
  text-align: center
  position: relative
```

But Intellij do not present me any way to supress this warnign. It confuses me when I am looking for actual errors on the Project folders

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with Intellij. It is using Sass default escaping characther.

The problem I was having is due to an issue with Libsass, which Gulp-sass uses under the hood to compile sass, instead of the original ruby implementation. Libsass does not need the escaping character, so when I escape to avoid Intellij error, it compiles the escape character as well.

I am using Gulp-ruby-sass now and everything works just fine, meaning I can escape the :host selector the way Intellij provides